# Wordpress ajax function parameter value not being passed

Tags: jquery, ajax, query, javascript, parameter

I am using wordpress ajax and following code not passing parameter value `metakey: id` to `$_POST["metakey"]`. So `var_dump($_POST)` shows `array(0) { }` and `$_REQUEST` shows `array()`

if I enter static value of variable in PHP function `$key=<any meta
 key>` then its works fine

```
jQuery(".selectbox").change(function(){
     var id = this.id;

     // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
      data: ({
        action: "get-mata-value",        
        metakey: id
      }),
      success:  function( response ) {     
                jQuery.each(response ,function(index,value){
                    jQuery('#' +id).append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
 }
    });




});
```

PHP:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get-mata-value", "get_mata_value");
function get_mata_value()
{   
    global $wpdb;
$key=$_POST["metakey"];
    $result=
 $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT      DISTINCT meta_value
    FROM        $wpdb->postmeta 
    WHERE       meta_key = %s               
    ",
    $key
) ); 
 return($result);

    exit();

}
```

EDIT:

Under chrome developer tool I see

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 XHR finished loading: POST

with following error:

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to
>   search for 'length' in

Comment: Looks like you missed the post in `js`.

Comment: Where did you find this method?

Comment: You JavaScript is screwed. Do like one or two google searches about "Ajax WordPress" and you'll get a great answer for the JAVASCRIPT side of this.

Comment: I have did a lot and also tried $.post and jquery.post but same issue. Please provide me solution as answer

Comment: Nice job doing a lot. It won't work. Look specifically at the JavaScript. Try looking at my decent comment and search for "Ajax WordPress".

Comment: Make sure your JS runs and is passing proper values. Try using Firebug or any other tool to Debug, `console.log` value you are passing.

Comment: did you check what is actually passed on the network? if the id is 0 you probably has a problem in your JS. A side from that, there is no way ypur server side will do anything useful, especially since it does not output anything.

Comment: What do you get if you run your backend query?

Comment: You can check out my in depth answer about AJAX load in wp on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31588401/629127) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with google api as stated in question by showing api related error message

> jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

So I have added following code snippet in theme functions.php that called previous version of google api. It has solved the issue of passing parameter value. All other code was already fine.

```
  //Making jQuery Google API

    function modify_jquery() {

        if (!is_admin()) {

            // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery

            wp_deregister_script('jquery');

            wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.1');

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        }

    }

    add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should read the codex on [**AJAX_in_Plugins**](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Secondly you should look at [**wp_localize_script**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to get the value for the admin-ajax url to your javascript.

```
$data = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', $data );
```

In your javascript, you are then meant to reference the localized data

```
jQuery(".selectbox").change(function(){
    var id = this.id;

    // do a POST ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: ({
            "action": "get-mata-value",
            "metakey": id
        }),
        success:  function( response ) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: All these methods have been tried, the only issue is parameter value is not being passed. Ajax is working if I put static value in PHP

Comment: Have you looked at `wp_send_json`?

Comment: Getting error chrome developer tool: jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to  search for 'length' in

Comment: I've updated the jquery code, but as you can see, it's just a pointer as to how you localize and get the ajax_url and not a correction on what you have.

Comment: Have you localized the admin ajax url, is it available on the frontend, test with `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. Not sure why, but `this.id` doesn't return value for me. So instead try using `jQuery(this).attr('id')`.

Also if this doesn't solve your problem, try `console.log(id)` before your ajax call and check what value you get.

Comment: I got id value on alert box

Comment: Do you have a test link for your site or are you doing this on local machine?

Comment: https://writerspublisher.com/wordpress/

Comment: Data is being sent, have you tried using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`? In your PHP, `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_REQUEST)`

Comment: print_r($_POST) Is showing array() that means parameter values are not being passed. It is the issue of this thread

Comment: And `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: same result for it

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error in the jQuery plugin. I don't know why, but it seems to be the roadblock on your development. I looked at my wordpress installation, and I use the same version of jQuery, but without the error.

I don't know if there is a plugin or theme that is causing a conflict. The usual remedy is to disable all plugins and themes and see if the problem goes away.

You might also try enqueueing older versions of jQuery (if that's possible) to see if that clears up the problem.

Perhaps it's the installation of wordpress that is broken. Could you do a fresh install of WP somewhere else? Your local machine might be a good candidate.

I'm sorry I don't know why you're getting this error, it just seems clear that until you clear that up, you won't be able to see if your AJAX is working or not.

**EDIT**: I'm wondering if the error is occurring while the data is being sent, or when the data is being returned. In `get_mata_value()`, instead of "return($result)", try "echo $result;". And instead of "exit();" try "wp_die();".  But instead of `$result` coming from the database, set it to a test value, like `$result = "I get by with a little help from my friends";`

I googled the error message from jQuery. See the last answer on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149836/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-length-in-trigge). I would change the first line of the change callback function from `var id=this.id;` to `var id=jQuery(this).id;`

Comment: var id=jQuery(this).id; shows no value